# How to Unit test Adobe Extended Script

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm working on adobe Indesign automation scripts. Since the javascript support from adobe is limited and customised, I cannot use jasmine or any testing frameworks to write my unit tests. So I was wondering should I extend a testing framework for my needs. Has anyone done this before, if so how can I start?

Answer (score 0):

Extendables library intends to port Jasmine Unit Testing to ExtendScript but I can't get it to work. I think it's a bit frozen since a while but I might be wrong : 
https://github.com/debrouwere/Extendables/tree/master/core-packages/testing/doc